# Local images are not showing on React App

Tags: reactjs

My local images are not showing. I have an application with just an image and it does not show although it does show when I inspect with F12. My App.jsx only has:

```
return (
    <>
      <img src={LOGO} alt='' />
    </>
    )
```

I tried importing the image like:

```
import LOGO from './assets/portfolio_logo.png'
```

I tried using `require()`; I tried having the images in the public folder; I tried having them in an `assets/` folder inside the `/src` folder. Nothing worked. Do you have any idea what might be done to make images show? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Note if you are not using create-react-app you might have to explicitly configure webpack to enable importing images such as jpeg png svg etc

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping all your images in a public folder as shown below:

[image]

You can add the following code to access the image from any react component,

```
 <img src='/assets/images/Call.svg' />
```

Keeping your assets in a public folder ensures that, you can access them from anywhere from the project, by just giving '/path_to_image'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. The common ways are not working. It might be something about versions of react-script, idk

Answer (score 0):

The problem was another component messing with global styles.