# Reactjs not showing local images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and recently ran into an issue. I'm saving a .jpg image locally in a public library [see screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6AER.png) and utilizing a relative path `src='../images/book-2.jpg'` to import the image into the locally hosted app (see full code below). The app is loading everything but the image [see screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yTLQ.png). I am not using webpack as some of the online threads discuss, and I have copied the settings listed in the following github folder [vs-code-setup-2022](https://github.com/john-smilga/vs-code-setup-2022/tree/main). I read through similar previous questions related to this issue (examples: [Local images are not showing on React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73290379/local-images-are-not-showing-on-react-app/77495826#77495826), [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images), and [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images).

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'

const BookList = () => {
  return (
    <section className='booklist'>
      <Book />
      <Book />
      <Book />
      <Book />
    </section>
  )
}

const Book = () => {
  return (
    <article className='book'>
      <Image />
      <Title />
      <Author />
    </article>
  )
}

const Image = () => (
  <img
    src='../images/book-2.jpg'
    alt='Friends, Lovers, and the Big Terrible Thing'
  />
)
const Title = () => <h2>Friends, Lovers, and the Big Terrible Thing</h2>
const Author = () => {
  return <h4>Matthew Perry</h4>
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))

root.render(<BookList />)
```

I tried the following solutions based on what I gathered from these and others fora without favorable results:

1. Using an absolute path `src='/images/book-2.jpg';`, but this didn't work.
2. Checking whether the web server is not serving the images, but I'm not seeing any 404 errors in the browser console.
3. Creating an import statement `import picture from "../images/book-2.jpg"; <img src={picture}/>`, but I received an error - ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:0-43
   Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../images/book-2.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
   You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
4. Using `{require()}` didn't help either.
5. Using two dots to import images in the like fashion `src='../images/book-2.jpg'`, which didn't work for me.

I'd appreciate any helpful hints to move past this.

Comment: "I am not using webpack" -- what _are_ you using then?

Comment: Point #3 seems to answer your question though: either move your image into /src or symlink it.